# Inner class which extends Asynctask and outer class extends Activity and then Extend outer class from another Activity. Is this a bad practice?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Is this bad practice?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public abstract class Asynch extends Activity {
    public abstract void doInBackgroundAbstract();
    public abstract void onPostExecuteAbstract();
    protected class AsynchtaskSubClass extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            doInBackgroundAbstract();
            return null;

        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result){
            onPostExecuteAbstract();
        }
    }

}

public class SomeActivity extends Asynch {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_classes);
        new AsynchtaskSubClass().execute();
    }
            private Document doc;
        @Override
        public void doInBackgroundAbstract() {
            // NETWORK OPERATION GOES HERE!
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("mySite").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecuteAbstract() {
            // Update UI Thread Here
            TextView myTextView = new TextView(SomeActivity.this);
            myTextView.setText(doc.select("a[href]").attr("abs:href").toString());
            setContentView(myTextView);

        }
```

This looks much cleaner to me. I do not have to keep on creating inner Asynchronous tasks or create a separate class to run an Asynchronous task. If I want to have an Asynchtask that I reused in many activities then I would simply extend Asynch and override the Abstract methods and keep that as a separate class. Is their anything wrong with doing this? The only problem I see is that if I need to use two or more Asynchronous tasks in one activity.

Comment: Yes, as you point out, if you need to use more than one `AsyncTask` in one `Activity`, you need to assign for each `AsyncTask` an `id` to handle when the result comes out. Otherwise, I see nothing wrong with this practice, just abit confusing. Cheers!

Comment: What is the best practice? It seems like the way I write android code is messy so I was trying to figure out a "cleaner" way. Any ideas to clean up Asynchtasks?

Comment: As far as I know, you better use `Thread`, and handle result by its `callback`. `AsyncTask` in some cases (I dont know for sure), after the job done, the thread still remains until the system call `gc`, that may harms your memory. But of course, `AsyncTask` or `Thread`, both has pros and cons. Choose thing that fits your purpose. Cheers!

Comment: You approach looks good and clear to me. The users just have to override the methods doInBackgroundAbstract() and onPostExecuteAbstract() and write the logic. You have anyway mentioned the limitation which cannot be ignored :).

Answer (score 0):

As you have already pointed out you cannot have more than one asynchronous tasks in your activity. Apart from that your class can extend only one other class, not more. 
So if you want an activity that extends ListActivity and has an asynchronous task you have to make another abstract asynch ("listActivityAsynch") class and so on. 
The other thing is that your code is not easily understandable for other programmers by just looking at SomeActivity. They first have to look at Asynch and understand the uncommon design that you have used. If you are the only one who works with this code it is probably fine. But if others have to work with it it would be best to follow common android practice which is to make in inner class.